# Are vector elements guaranteed to be in order?

Tags: c++, vector

I understand that having pointers to elements of a vector is a bad idea, because upon expanding, the memory addresses involved will change, therefore invalidating the pointer(s). However, what if I were to simply use an integer that holds the index number of the element I want to access? Would that be invalidated as the vector grows in size? What I am thinking of looks something like this:

```
    #include <vector>

    class someClass{
    string name
    public: string getName(){return name;}
    };

    vector<someClass> vObj;
    int currIdx;
    string search;
    cout<<"Enter name: ";
    cin>>search;

    for(int i=0; i<vObj.size(); i++){
      if(vObj[i].getName()==search)
         currIdx = i;}
```

Comment: Yes; vector entries maintain a consistent position within the vector assuming you don't remove any items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the index numbers are of course not invalidated when the vector expands. They are invalidated (in the sense that you no longer find the same elements at a constant index) if you erase a previous element, though:

`vector: 3 5 1 6 7 4`

Here, `vector[2] == 1`. But if you erase `vector[1]` (the 5), then afterwards, `vector[2] == 6`.

Answer (score 3):

I think the title of your question and what you seem to be asking do not really match. No vector is by definition guaranteed to be sorted, so elements won't be "in order".

Moreover, *all* iterators and references to elements of a vector will be invalidated upon insertion **only** if reallocation occurs (i.e. when the size of the vector exceeds its capacity). Otherwise, iterators and references *before* the point of insertion will not be invalidated (see Paragraph 23.3.6.5/1 of the C++11 Standard).

Storing an index is only subject to a potential *logical* invalidation: if you insert elements into the vector in a position *prior* to the one you are indexing, the element you were indexing will be shifted one position to the right, and the same index will now refer to a different element ; likewise, if you erase an element prior to the position you were indexing, the element you were indexing will be shifted on position to the left - and your index may now refer to a position which is out-of-bounds.

Comment: You're right, that's my bad. My question title was poorly phrased. But thanks for answering it despite that though!

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't, as the system will simply allocate more memory and then do a memcopy.

Order should be preserved in the std::vector STL template.

And yes, if you delete elements the ordering will change. But if you are going to be doing a lot of deletes, use a different data structure such as a linked list.

Answer (score 0):

No, the index numbers are not invalidated when the vector is expanded. Since you're declaring that the vector container object is not a pointer `vector<someClass>` instead of `vector<someClass*>`, your pointed to element will be preserved as well.

Comment: Alright, what if I use     vector<someClass*>     instead? Would that alter the behavior of the vector in a way I don't know about? I do intend to use it that way, because ultimately I intend to store objects of 3 different classes, all of which share the same parent class, into one vector, therefore I am going to use something like     vector<someClass*>     and then dereference the object I intend to access, and static_cast it back into the appropriate type before doing whatever it is I want to do.

Comment: Inserting items (naked pointers) re-allocates the array in contiguous memory space, invalidating the pointers. You can use a shared or smart pointer for this. Look at `boost::shared_ptr`